# Hibernate annotations - names for constraints

Tags: java, hibernate

I started using annotation in a project as an excuse to get the hang of them and I have a question.

I created the domain classes for each table in my database and I use annotations to connect the members with the columns, using validation and stuff like that. I also use unique index constraints by using uniqueConstraints and where I have many to one or many to many relationships I use jointable with join columns.

My questions are two and might be a bit naive,

1) I set the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to create in the persistence xml and then run the app so as to create the database through the app. I then went to the database and exported the schema creation sql file. Is this a valid practice to get the creation schema sql? Also, I noticed that while the constaint names I used in the annotations for foreign keys and indexes were transferred but in my many to many relationship the names were the generated names rather than the ones I specified. Is there a reason for it other than I probably did something wrong?

2) If I get the schema from above, fix the names of the constraints to what I want and then run it to create the database, and run the app but with setting the persistense xml option hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto set to update will it cause problems since the name of the constraint might not match the one in the annotation?

For the many to many relationship, this is the two domain class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SOLUTION")
public class Solution {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SOLUTION_CODE", length = 20, nullable = false)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20, message = "The solution code size is not within limits (0-20)")
    @NotNull(message = "The solution code cannot be null")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "SOLUTION_DESCRIPTION", length = 200, nullable = false)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 200, message = "The solution description is not within limits (0-200)")
    @NotNull(message = "The solution description cannot be null")
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "solutionList")
    private List<Category> categories;

    public Solution() {
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_CODE", length = 20, nullable = false)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20, message = "The category code size is not within limits (0-20)")
    @NotNull(message = "The category code cannot be null")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION", length = 200, nullable = false)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 200, message = "The category description is not within limits (0-200)")
    @NotNull(message = "The category description cannot be null")
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "SOLUTION_CATEGORY_MAPPING",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "CATEGORY_CODE",
                    referencedColumnName = "CATEGORY_CODE",
                    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_SOLUTION_CATEGORY_CATEGORY_CODE")),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "SOLUTION_CODE",
                    referencedColumnName = "SOLUTION_CODE",
                    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_SOLUTION_CATEGORY_SOLUTION_CODE")))
    private List<Solution> solutionList;

    public Category() {
    }
}
```

I would expect the foreign key constraint to have the names I specified but they just have generated ones

Edit: Also I was wondering if someone can overdo it with annotations and if they might affect performance?

Answer (score 0):

many to many table can be set using `@JoinTable`

regarding constraint names. well, hibernate doesn't support every feature of every database. therefore schema generate is only to help you. before putting it on production you have to read it, fix it and test it. also putting hibernate on production with `auto.ddl=update` is VERY bad idea. don't do it. instead always use sql files to build schama.

with constraint names problem isn't big. you can create your own and hibernate shouldn't complain even in `validate` mode.

also consider using db migration tools, like flyway